# ARM assembly: bad instruction "mov32"

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-toolchain

I wanted to load a 32bit constant into a register and I found a pseudo-instruction "mov32" on which can do this ([mov32 pseudo-instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/Cihcfbhg.html)). Then I write an assembly file which includes:

```
MOV32 r0, #0xABCDEF12
```

And compiled it with linaro toolchain(version 13.04):

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 test.s -o test.o
```

But it failed with message:

```
Error: bad instruction `mov32 r0, #0xABCDEF12'
```

I don't know if it's the matter of unified assembly language. In case, I wrote ".syntax unified" in source code and tested again, but also failed. Does GNU toolchain support ARM pseudo-instruction like "mov32", "ldr r0, =address" etc. ? If does, how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: ldr rx,=0x12345678 will work for you with the gnu tools.

Comment: You are using gnu assembler with arm assembler pseudo instructions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been mentioned by a commenter, `MOV32` is a [pseudo-instruction supported by ARM's own development tools](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289879354.htm). Since you're using the GNU toolchain you've got a couple of options:

You can, as dwelch mentioned, use `LDR R0,=0xABCDEF12`.
This is also a pseudo-instruction, which will result in the immediate constant being placed in a *literal pool* (small chunks of data scattered throughout the code section), which then is loaded using a PC-relative `LDR`.
If the constant can be encoded as `imm8 ROR n` (which it can't in your case, but let's say you had 0x80000000) then the `LDR =` psedo-instruction will be translated into a single `MOV` and won't add anything to the literal pool.

---

You could also use the instructions that `MOV32` translates into:

```
MOVW R0,#0xEF12  
MOVT R0,#0xABCD
```

This requires an ARMv6T2 or later.

Answer (score 5):

In the GNU assembler, one can synthesize `mov32` the following way:

```
.macro mov32, reg, val
    movw \reg, #:lower16:\val
    movt \reg, #:upper16:\val
.endm
```

That'll work for ARMv7. If you'd want the "generic" behaviour (substitute it with `ldr reg,=val` where `movw`/`movt` don't exist), add a sprinkling of `#ifdef`.

(Credit where credit is due: This comes from [`arch/arm/mach-tegra/sleep.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-tegra/sleep.h#L68) of the ARM Linux kernel sources, not an invention of mine)

Comment: Protip: Link to a git hash instead of a branch.